# Incrementing iterator (iter) in Python

Tags: python, c++, string, iterator

I have the following string for example:

```
s = "string"
```

I'm trying to maintain an iterator to this string object.

```
it = iter(s)
```

I know that I can use a loop and increment the `it` using `next` call

```
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    print(next(it))
```

This is going to print all the characters in this string.

But I have couple of things that I would like the iterator to do as I do using C++ iterator on `std::list`.

**1.) To return the element that iterator currently points to.**

```
   // In C++, I would do,

   std::string str = "string";

   std::string::iterator it = str.begin();
   *it; // gets the value of element
```

**2.) To get the index of element the iterator is at.**

So that I'm able to get the sub-string using Python slicing method:

E.g:

```
s = "string"
s[0:iter_index_in_integer]
```

In C++, I could use iterators:

```
   std::string str = "string";
   std::string::iterator it = str.begin();
   std::string(it, it+3);
```

Is it possible to increment the iterator in Python like that? If not then I could use the index of element the iterator currently points to and how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's built-in do not provide anything that allows you to get the "current element" of an iterator. The *only* operation that an iterator must support is `next` to get the following element *and* advance the iteration.

However it's quite simple to write your own iterator that implements other operations:

```
class AugmentedIterator(object):
    _sentinel = object()

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iterator = iterator
        self.value = self._sentinel

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.value is not self._sentinel:
            self.value, val = self._sentinel, self.value
            return val
        return next(self.iterator)

    def peek(self, default=_sentinel):
        if self.value is not self._sentinel:
            return self.value
        try:
            self.value = next(self.iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            if default is not self._sentinel:
                return default
            raise
        else:
            return self.value
```

Now, given *any* iterator `it` you can wrap it into an `AugmentedIterator` and whenever you want you can call `peek()` to check the current element.

Note that there is no such thing as `end()`, since iterators can easily be infinite. The only way to know whether the iterator doesn't have any more elements is to call `next` and see if it raises a `StopIteration`.

For your second request you can use `itertools.islice` to get a slice of the iterator. Note however that `islice` does *python* slicing, which allows out-of-bounds indexes:

```
In [19]: list(islice('string', 0, 1000))
Out[19]: ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Here the index `1000` since it's bigger then the string length is just taken to mean: until the end. This is consistent with slicing:

```
In [20]: 'string'[:1000]
Out[20]: 'string'
```

In C++ you'd get an error trying to use `it+1000` if the string has length 6. (Not 100% sure, but since pointers are iterables you'd surely get some troubles at least in *some* circumstances).

---

In general the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) package contains quite a few useful functions (at the end of the documentation there are some recipes using them). Python also provides some iterator related functions such as:

- [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate): to iterate over elements and get the relative indices.
- `map`/`filter`/`reduce`
- [`iter(callable, sentinel)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter): allows you to obtain an iterator given a function without arguments:

  ```
  for chunk in iter(lambda: file_object.read(4096), ''):
      handle(chunk)
  ```

  Is equivalent to:

  ```
  while True:
      chunk = file_object.read(4096)
      if chunk == '':
          break
      handle(chunk)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in `enumerate()` function:

```
for index, element in enumerate(mystring):
    print index
    print element
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
import itertools
s = "mystring"
s2 = ''.join(itertools.islice(s, 0, 3))
```

But really, rather than attempt to directly translate C++ idioms, you should find the Pythonic way to do whatever it is you want, which will probably end up being more concise anyway.